# Is the last element of the expanded form of an acronym separated by a comma or an 'and'?

Tags: commas, acronyms

I am writing a report, and got to a point where I was talking about the acronym

> CALMS

Which stands for:

> Culture, Automation, Lean, Measure

and here lies my question. Should it be another *comma* or an *and*?

> CALMS stands for Culture, Automation, Lean, Measure, Sharing ...

or

> CALMS stands for Culture, Automation, Lean, Measure and Sharing.

Also similarly should the components of an acronym be capitalized? ie:

> CALMS stands for **C**ulture, **A**utomation...

Comment: Who invented that acronym? How does that person write it? Also is your last question about emphasizing bold? You are capitalizing the words in every example already.

Comment: I saw the acronym in a lecture and it was presented as the word CALMS with the rest of the letters underneath each of the starting words. the last question is if it's correct to be capitalizing it or not

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be specific to a case where an acronym is a *list* of items (compare NASA in whihc the *and* is required and not where you're trying to put it).

This is largely a matter of taste/convention, but: When an acronym is used as a mnemoonic like this appears to be, a common convention is to use bullet points.  Highlighting in some appropriate way is probably useful.  I would also consider semicolons, that way if you use an expanded version of the list with explanations the semicolons separate the list items (which may themselves have commas) and the style is consistent.